# Help with a summation+inequality problem.

Tags: sequences-and-series, inequality, summation

I need help in solving for all possible x values for the below inequality:
(Note: $x \in N)$

$$\sum^x_{k=1}\frac{k^2+k+1}{k(k+1)(k+1)!} \leq \frac{599}{600}$$

I think the series is telescopic; I'm not sure how to prove it...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We have:
$$ \frac{1}{k\cdot k!}-\frac{1}{(k+1)\cdot (k+1)!} = \frac{(k+1)^2-k}{k(k+1)(k+1)!}=\frac{k^2+k+1}{k(k+1)(k+1)!},$$
bingo. That gives:
$$ \sum_{k=1}^{N}\frac{k^2+k+1}{k(k+1)(k+1)!} = 1-\frac{1}{(N+1)(N+1)!} $$
hence we just need to find the greatest $N$ such that $(N+1)(N+1)!\leq 600$. It is just $N=\color{red}{4}$.

Comment: Thank you! But largest N value is 4 right? According to the inequality at the end, greatest N should be 4.

Comment: @Kugelblitz: sure, sorry. Now fixed.

Comment: Please don't be. You help me by answering all my answers and respond to my queries patiently. Thank you.